# SELECT em uma tabela pai onde TODOS os filhos estão em uma mesma situação - MariaDB/MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Preciso fazer um select em uma tabela pai, onde todos os filhos dessa tabela PRECISAM estar em uma mesma situação.

Por exemplo:

Na tabela pai tenho os seguintes campos:
`pai_id, pai_nome`

Na tabela filho tenho os seguintes campos:
`filho_id, idade, pai_id`

Nesse exemplo, preciso fazer um SELECT que liste o nome dos pais onde **TODOS** os filhos tenham uma determinada idade, se pelo menos um dos filhos não tiver essa idade, o pai não deve aparecer na lista.

Fiz o select dessa forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
pai_nome
FROM pai p
INNER JOIN filho f ON (f.pai_id = p.pai_id)
WHERE f.idade = 15
```

Mas nesse caso, apenas se um dos filhos atender ao critério de idade, já é suficiente para que o pai seja listado. Não consigo pensar numa logica que atenda, para que a regra seja aplicada a TODOS os filhos.

Comment: um select de todos os pais que só tem filhos gemeos ?!

Comment: Isso mesmo. Eu só usei pai e filho como exemplo. Mas a ideia seria essa.
Mas não necessariamente o PAI tem que ter mais um filho. Se ele só tiver um filho, e o filho atender ao critério de idade, ele já viria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você seleciona todos que tem filhos com idade = 14 (por exemplo), 
e depois remove todos que tiverem filho com idade diferente de 14.

Segue o código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.pai_id,
    p.pai_nome
FROM pai p
INNER JOIN filho f ON (f.pai_id = p.pai_id) and f.idade = 14
where p.pai_id not in (select x.pai_id from filho x where x.idade != f.idade and x.pai_id = p.pai_id);
```

Usando o `Not Exists` ficou ainda mais rápido:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    p.pai_id,
    p.pai_nome
FROM pai p
INNER JOIN filho f ON (f.pai_id = p.pai_id) and f.idade = 14
where not exists (select 1 from filho x where x.idade != f.idade and x.pai_id = p.pai_id);
```

Coloquei no SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3c97e5/5

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!